# Dgrid Horizontall Scroll not working in Safari

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I have face few issues when test dgrid on ipad or MAC.
1) dgrid not take width in percentage
2) horizontal scrolling bar is not shown as i have position absolute in .dgrid-scroller.
What mistake I have made?

I have an example in which horizontal scrolling is not working 
http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/demos/gantt/